# Counting words in a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given a **list**:

```
lst = ['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'pears', 'pears', 'banana']
```

and a **dictionary**

```
dict = {'orange': 4, 'apple':2, 'pears': 1}
```

If a string from the list already exist in dict, update the value. Else, add a new key and its number of occurence.

Result:

```
dict = {'apple':3, 'orange':5, 'kiwi':1, 'pears':3, 'banana':1}
```

I tried:

```
for string in lst:
    if string in dict:
        dict[string] += 1
    else:
        dict[string] = 1
return dict
```

This gives me the order from the dictionary and adds the new strings to it. What I need to do is, add string by string to dictionary and if the string already exists then it can add the value. So the order is lst strings like this

**What it gives:**

```
dict = {'orange': 5, 'apple': 3, 'pears': 3, 'kiwi': 1, 'banana': 1}
```

**What I want:**

```
dict = {'apple':3, 'orange':5, 'kiwi':1, 'pears':3, 'banana':1}
```

Comment: What version of Python? See [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39980323)

Comment: Why you'd want `'apple': 1`? Your code seems OK.

Comment: Also don't name your variables `dict` dict is python class, and by naming your variable like that you override python builtin class.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at high performance collections, namely [counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import  Counter
a = Counter(['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi', 'pears', 'pears', 'banana'])
print(a)
>>> print(a)
Counter({'pears': 2, 'apple': 1, 'orange': 1, 'kiwi': 1, 'banana': 1})
>>> print(a['something not in original']
0
>>> print(a['pears']
2
>>> print(a['apple']
1
```